# Mongo db Write order

Tags: javascript, mongodb

This post will be quite long, if you are a mongo god and you want to help me anyway, I thank you from the bottom of my heart. I try to be as exaustive as possible, with all the data I collected.

I'm experiencing some strange behaviour in my MongoDD database, and I'm questionning mongodb's write order.

I have logged bugs, that only happen at the time of the execution, that made me think that we have a timming problem here, but the requesting is so slow, that I don't understand how It can happen in suck conditions

Starting points:

- All ObjectIds are auto-given by mongo, I never set them on my side
- This objectId is indexed (obviously) and unique
- I use the timestamp in those requests ids to query the DB, using this request:

```
    db.getCollection('eventStore').find({
      '_id': {
        '$gt': ObjectId("5d285c784460c502cc66ff9b"),
        '$lte': ObjectId("5d285cf7856cda0266215c77")
      }
    })
```

- The results of this request are then streamed using the basic Node.js client possibilies:

```
    collection.find({
        '_id': {
          ...(lower ? { '$gt': lower } : {}),
          '$lte': higher
        }
      }).sort({ _id: 1 }).stream({
        transform: (element) => {
          logger.info(`Exiting Get events by range::${JSON.stringify(lower)}::${JSON.stringify(higher)}`)
          logger.info(`Parse event::${JSON.stringify(element)}}`)
          return // PARSED EVENT
        }
      })
```

- At this point, I know that the `.sort({ _id: 1 })` is probably useless, but I keep it here anyway, just in case.
- The requesting procedure is quite slow: I query the upperbound in order to have the eventStore's offset, then the view's offset, then I query the store in order to have all events between these boundaries.
- The sample of mongo's data:

```
    /* 1 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d285cf77f6482027108c15c"),
        "events" : [ 
            // Some events
        ]
    }

    /* 2 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d285cf77f6482027108c15d"),
        "events" : [
            // Some events
        ]
    }

    /* 3 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d285cf7856cda0266215c77"),
        "events" : [ 
            // Some events
        ]
    }
```

Expected Mongo Behaviour:

- Mongo is self assigning the Ids, so I expect that when the ID
  ObjectId("5d285cf7856cda0266215c77") is stored in base, all the IDs with a older timestamp are stored safe in the base already. ==> No backpedaling
- The timestamp encoded in the ObjectId (when it's self given by mongo) is the one when it's written and persisted in the DB, not the one when it's received by Mongo.

Actual behaviour (as logged in the logger's function):

- Only the first and the last _ids have been seen in the logger's function

```
    {"message":"Exiting Get events by range::\"5d285c784460c502cc66ff9b\"::\"5d285cf7856cda0266215c77\"","level":"info","timestamp":"2019-07-12 10:12:07"} 
    {"message":"Parse event::{\"_id\":\"5d285cf77f6482027108c15c\",\"events\":[ // Data ]}}","level":"info","timestamp":"2019-07-12 10:12:07"} 
    {"message":"Exiting Get events by range::\"5d285c784460c502cc66ff9b\"::\"5d285cf7856cda0266215c77\"","level":"info","timestamp":"2019-07-12 10:12:07"} 
    {"message":"Parse event::{\"_id\":\"5d285cf7856cda0266215c77\",\"events\":[ // Data ]}}","level":"info","timestamp":"2019-07-12 10:12:07"}
```

- As it seems:

  1. Or the event _id: ObjectId("5d285cf77f6482027108c15d") was not in base at the time of the call, but the older _id: ObjectId("5d285cf7856cda0266215c77") was.
  2. Or my request or stream is invalid at the time of the call (but now, returns the correct answer)
  3. Something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Mongo is self assigning the Ids, so I expect that when the ID ObjectId("5d285cf7856cda0266215c77") is stored in base, all the IDs with a older timestamp are stored safe in the base already. ==> No backpedaling

Mongo `_ids` are `ObjectIds` which are:

> - a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
> - a 5-byte random value, and
> - a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

These are often generated in **application driver** code (on the server that's sending data to mongo).

This means that:

1. Network delays can create out of order records
2. Application servers with clock drift can create out of order records
3. 5 byte random values don't necessarily move forward within the same second (which can create out of order records, even if mongo is assigning the _ids)
4. NTP updates can create out of order records (even on mongo -- it doesn't do any smearing when updating the clock)
5. Leap seconds can create out of order records

If you take a look at the _ids that you shared, the first 4 bytes (8 characters) of `5d285cf77f6482027108c15d` & `5d285cf7856cda0266215c77` (`5d285cf7`) both share the same timestamp because they happened in the same second after the epoch.

Comment: Yup, I noticed that both _ids are close in term of time. However, my main concern is the following: during the time it took for the base to query the top of my event store Id and the top of my view's id, the base doesn't seem to have managed to store an event happenning litteraly the same second. But, yes, if the ID is generated driver side, it can be the case. What is my alternative ? does mongo have an incremental ID generated by mongo itself ?

Comment: Something like https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_autoincrement_sequence would have been great, but I rly need the atomicty between the increment and the rest, and I need this to be server side. Ie. I really need to assure that at the time that the ID 4 is written that the ids 1 2 and 3 are stored and accessible in the database.

Comment: Just checking, are you using the `forceServerObjectId` option (in node at least -- unsure what it is in drivers)? For server-created _ids, you have to deal with network delays & clock drift on all of your servers

Comment: Nope, I didn't know it was an option. Thanks for that, I will try that out. I only have 1 mongo server, and many Node process accessing it. If it's created by mongo, it should fullfill my needs at least for now, correct ? (I don't know how I can have delay and clock drift if mongo is running on one server, but I may be missing something)

Comment: It sounds like it should work! If you're worried about getting every single event (say for auditing/financials/something like that), you'd theoretically still have to worry about NTP updates on the mongo server moving time backwards, leap seconds, and failovers. But, practically speaking, you should be fine